# Cannot center text in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, margin, padding

The problem is (which you can see in the pictures below) that the "doner", "Wallet", and "Amount" aren't centered on the page.

I've tried changing the margin and padding and moving divs around and etc, but nothing seems to be working and I don't understand what is wrong or how to fix it. (it is hard to see in the code snippet because it's not full screen so I'm just going to give a link to the HTML [here](https://pastebin.com/nHXwG7pz))

The only issue I can find is when I inspect element on google chrome. When I hover my mouse over `<div class="container">` (the one underneath `div class="learn-more">`) It shows that the div container is wider on the right side, but I can't find why!

Thanks for the help! If you need any clarification please ask, I couldn't find anything to fix my problem online so I came here.

Here's a picture of what I mean as well:

[image: image1]

[image]

Comment: Please see how to make a [mcve]. Questions shouldn't require visiting external sites, since they tend to change over time and are out of control of this site, making the question eventually meaningless.

Comment: Shoot you're totally right, it was just hard for me to show one peice of the code because I honestly didn't know what was wrong, and it looked gross putting it all in my question. I'll definitely do that next time though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential problem with your code is the markup. You're using the Bootstrap & putting some div directly inside the container & then another container inside this div. See what I mean:

[image: the screenshot]
Here are the first three rules from the 3rd Bootstrap documentation you should follow when building your HTML:

- Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
  .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
  immediate children of rows.

So, my suggestion is to revise your HTML layout and use the Bootstrap as it intended instead of applying some hacks.

Start from rearranging containers in the way that the content would be put inside columns and all of the wrappers would be outside of the containers or inside the columns.

Comment: Perfect, so if I just change the class container it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

put your content that you want to center in a div like

```
<div class="box">your content...</div>
```

in your css file just add this :

```
.box{

display:inline-block;
position:relative;
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);

}
```

you can also use a `float left` for your 3 titles and set the same witdh and height for the three with text-center proprety